# Horizontally mirror a brainflak program

Tags: code-golf, brain-flak

Your task is to write a program or function which takes a pure brainflak program as input (assume it contains only balanced `()[]{}<>`), and output a visually mirrored copy of it.

If you reversed a brainflak program as a string, say `({}())` (add one to an input), you would get `))(}{(`, which is not valid.

Instead, you should mirror it, by reversing the direction of the parentheses/brackets/braces/angle-brackets, like what you would see if the program was placed in front of a mirror: `((){})`.

Test cases (`???` means anything is okay):

```
()               -> ()
({}[{}])         -> ([{}]{})
()[]             -> []()
<(){}[]>         -> <[]{}()>
([{<()[]{}<>>}]) ->([{<<>{}[]()>}])
(a)              -> ???
{>               -> ???
))(}{(           -> ???
()↵[]            -> ???
```

This is a code golf challenge, shortest answer per language wins.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the invalid test cases as they add nothing to the challenge, and instead add some edge cases, or something maybe a little longer

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing What edge cases would you recommend?

Comment: Maybe something like `([{<()[]{}<>>}])` or similarly convoluted?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I'll add it, but I'm keeping the invalid test cases to remove any possible confusion

Comment: I think I know exactly what prompted this challenge heh :P

Comment: A nice brain-flak term to describe the inputs: a **pure** brain-flak program contains only `(){}[]<>` and is perfectly balanced.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Updated, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This feels like a dupe to me. Maybe a subset of a challenge that asked us to reverse a string, replacing characters that can be "mirrored".

Comment: @Shaggy I searched, but couldn't find anything

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms, Yeah, I can't find it either. Either I'm not searching right (entirely possible; I'm a few pints deep!) or it's still in the Sandbox.

Comment: I am disappointed (but still hopeful) that there is no answer in brainflak.

Comment: @JoKing Oh wait, wrong challenge. I also recently posted a different question about reversing code.

Comment: @StianYttervik Oh wait, wrong challenge. I also recently posted a different question about reversing code. Nvm my last comment.

Answer (score 10):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 3 bytes

```
Ｓ‖Ｔ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMzr6C0JLgEyE7X0NS05gpKTctJTS4JKUrMK07LL8rV0LT@/18jutpGQzM6trrWxs6uNlbzv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: `Ｓ` reads the input and implicitly echos it, while `‖` is the mirroring operator, which normally just reverses the input, but the `Ｔ` modifies it to mirror the characters at the same time.

Comment: +1 right primitive for the job

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>51 47</s>  44 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @xnor*

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(c=>c^68%c/3%8).reverse()+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7RCsIgFMbx@55iDMbOYbRdBLEL50WvIQbDNIo1h9ZuxGc3jSCaXn78zw/v4zpaYW7Lcz/riwxqCHagp5dS0oDF9jEuIAYqzse@Et2h6rE1cpXGSsCmroPQs9WTbCd9BQUlYFn8PcSi6wrA3TZ0njnPf/k3TKPzeY6Ml7nLeC4TwGhzupEJiy4gzWTmSNKdJ5SmD33ytBKanHgS1/AG)

#### How?

For each pair of characters, we can switch from the 1st to the 2nd character (and vice versa) by XOR'ing the ASCII code with \$1\$, \$2\$ or \$6\$.

```
 char 1 | code | XOR | code | char 2
--------+------+-----+------+--------
   '('  |   40 |  1  |   41 |  ')'
   '<'  |   60 |  2  |   62 |  '>'
   '['  |   91 |  6  |   93 |  ']'
   '{'  |  123 |  6  |  125 |  '}'
```

Given an ASCII code \$c\$, we can turn it into the correct XOR value by using the following function:

$$f(c)=\left\lfloor((68 \bmod c)/3)\bmod 8\right\rfloor$$

```
   c  | 68 mod c |   / 3  | mod 8 | floor
------+----------+--------+-------+-------
   40 |    28    |  9.333 | 1.333 |   1
   41 |    27    |    9   |   1   |   1
------+----------+--------+-------+-------
   60 |     8    |  2.667 | 2.667 |   2
   62 |     6    |    2   |   2   |   2
------+----------+--------+-------+-------
   91 |    68    | 22.667 | 6.667 |   6
   93 |    68    | 22.667 | 6.667 |   6
  123 |    68    | 22.667 | 6.667 |   6
  125 |    68    | 22.667 | 6.667 |   6
```

Comment: Why `Buffer(s)` instead of `s.split\`\``?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms `[...s]` would be shorter than using `split`. But this answer is working on ASCII codes, not on characters.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. (I've also never though of using the `...` operator on strings, that's handy to know)

Comment: I brute forced some expressions for the XOR value table and got `68%c/3%8`, which seems to work for 3 bytes shorter: [TIO](https://tio.run/##Zc7RCsIgFMbx@55iDMbOYbRdBLEL50WvIQbDNIo1h9ZuxGc3jSCaXn78zw/v4zpaYW7Lcz/riwxqCHagp5dS0oDF9jEuIAYqzse@Et2h6rE1cpXGSsCmroPQs9WTbCd9BQUlYFn8PcSi6wrA3TZ0njnPf/k3TKPzeY6Ml7nLeC4TwGhzupEJiy4gzWTmSNKdJ5SmD33ytBKanHgS1/AG "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda x:x[::-1].translate('>]<[)('*20+'}_{'*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqiLaykrXMFavpCgxrzgnsSRVQ90u1iZaU0Ndy8hAW702vhrI0PxfUJSZV6KRpqGkEW1TXWsXq6mkqfkfAA)

Python has a convenient string method `translate` that accepts a translation string `s`, and maps each character `c` to `s[ord(c)]`. So, we just need to make a translation string with the right characters at the positions of ASCII values `[40, 41, 60, 62, 91, 93, 123, 125]` of `()<>[]{}`.

The ideal would be to make the table like `'????????'*16`, putting the correct character for each ASCII value modulo 8. Unfortunately, the values `[40, 41, 60, 62, 91, 93, 123, 125]` are not distinct modulo 8, and the first modulus making them distinct is 18, which would mean something like `'??????????????????'*6`.

However, conveniently, the lowest 6 ASCII values `[40, 41, 60, 62, 91, 93]` are distinct modulo 6. That lets us handle them with `'>]<[)('*20`, translating ASCII values 0 through 119. For the remaining two, 123 and 125, we use `'}_{'*2` to hit the next 6 ASCII values 120 to 125. Python 3 lets us stop there, unlike Python 2, which requires the translation string to be length 256 exactly.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13</s>  12 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @JonathanAllan*

```
O&80%15‘^OỌṚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99fzcJA1dD0UcOMOP@Hu3se7pz1//9/jehqGw3N6NjqWhs7u9pYTQA)

#### How?

The idea here is to XOR the ASCII codes to turn each character into its mirrored counterpart, like I did in my [JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195606/58563). But we use a formula that is bit golfier in Jelly:

$$f(c)=((c\text{ & }80)\bmod 15)+1$$

where \$\text{&}\$ is a bitwise AND.

```
 char | code | and 80 | mod 15 |  + 1 | XOR code | new char
------+------+--------+--------+------+----------+----------
  '(' |   40 |    0   |    0   |   1  |    41    |   ')'
  ')' |   41 |    0   |    0   |   1  |    40    |   '('
------+------+--------+--------+------+----------+----------
  '<' |   60 |   16   |    1   |   2  |    62    |   '>'
  '>' |   62 |   16   |    1   |   2  |    60    |   '<'
------+------+--------+--------+------+----------+----------
  '[' |   91 |   80   |    5   |   6  |    93    |   ']'
  ']' |   93 |   80   |    5   |   6  |    91    |   '['
  '{' |  123 |   80   |    5   |   6  |   125    |   '}'
  '}' |  125 |   80   |    5   |   6  |   123    |   '{'
```

#### Commented

```
O&80%15‘^OỌṚ - a monadic link taking a string, e.g. "(<>[])"
O            - convert the input to ASCII codes --> [40, 60, 62, 91, 93, 41]
 &80         - bitwise AND with 80              --> [ 0, 16, 16, 80, 80,  0]
    %15      - modulo 15                        --> [ 0,  1,  1,  5,  5,  0]
       ‘     - increment                        --> [ 1,  2,  2,  6,  6,  1]
         O   - input to ASCII codes again       --> [40, 60, 62, 91, 93, 41]
        ^    - bitwise XOR                      --> [41, 62, 60, 93, 91, 40]
          Ọ  - convert back to characters       --> ")><][("
           Ṛ - reverse                          --> "([]<>)"
```

Comment: I've used up all of my votes for today, imaginary +1

Comment: You can save one if you avoid the register use by taking advantage of chaining rules and repeating `O` like so: `O&80%15‘^OỌU` (side note: personally I go for `Ṛ` when `U`'s depth action is not required, so would do `O&80%15‘^OỌṚ`)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
º2äθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0C6jw0vO7fj/X6O6Nrq6NlYTAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W@f/QLqPDS87t@K@k8KhtkoJSpb29zv9oJQ1NJR0FJY3q2ujq2lgIWzM6FkTbaGgCRWPtwGLR1TYg8epaGzs7kLpYAA)

**Explanation**

```
º    | Mirror (i.e. "({}[{}])" -> "({}[{}])([{}]{})"
 2ä  | Split into two pieces
   θ | Take the last piece
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 1 [byte](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
↔
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyMTk0,i=JTI3JTI4JTVCJTdCJTNDJTI4JTI5JTVCJTVEJTdCJTdEJTNDJTNFJTNFJTdEJTVEJTI5JTI3,v=8)

Surprised that this is the first 1-byte answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
|.rplc(;"0|.)@'([{<>}])'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1NC8IwDIbv@xVhlyTgys41loHgyZPX0tNwiAiK166/vaaObmKghDzvR@@5NTjBwQLCDnqw@joDx8v5lGfzfj1G2rf9bHhA8lFcCoyZm@Y63p4wAVJMPha4EKybGKGzX8eqUXHGtCl/WR9@Uz5ULl5TxK5qQqzJoPc62w8irohqL821TXlpjEncwvMH)

Test cases by Jonah.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>32</s></sup> 25 bytes

```
'([{<)]}>'|.@([{~8|4+i.)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU29CsJADN77FMElCdrDwUFKegiCk5PrkUks6uIDXM9XP3OWa8VASPL95ZlXDgfoO0DYwBY669bB8XI@ZaQQhTV5HN3B9vd@3K0fjjVz09yu9xcMgBRTiEkZJwTrJEZou69i5qgoY1qYP2/QX1fQikswF7GvnBCbU@2ea/kg4gtp8pJc0wwviTGJn/D8AQ)

Quick explanation:

- Find the index of each input char within the string `'([{<)]}>'`.
- Add 4 to it to get its mirror
- Take that mod 8 to handle wrapping around to the beginning
- Use the result to index back into `'([{<)]}>'`
- And reverse that result

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY1NC8IwDIbv@xVhlyTgys41loHgyZPX0tNwiAiK166/vaaObmKghDzvR@@5NTjBwQLCDnqw@joDx8v5lGfzfj1G2rf9bHhA8lFcCoyZm@Y63p4wAVJMPha4EKybGKGzX8eqUXHGtCl/WR9@Uz5ULl5TxK5qQqzJoPc62w8irohqL821TXlpjEncwvMH) using `rplc`

Comment: @GalenIvanov, v nice! i think it's different enough in both concept and implementation that you should feel free to post separately.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll post it separately.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 20 bytes

```
O^$`.

T`([{<>}])`Ro
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w3z9OJUGPiyskQSO62sauNlYzISj//38NTS6N6troaiCfS0MzOpbLRkMTyI@14wIpA4lU19rYgZQDAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
O`.
```

Sort individual characters...

```
$
```

... by substitution value (constant empty string, therefore keeps original order)...

```
^
```

... with reversed sort order (i.e. reversing the string).

```
T`([{<>}])
```

Substitute each character of `([{<>}])`...

```
`Ro
```

... with the matching character from the reverse of that string, thus mirroring those characters.

Comment: Note that in Retina 1 you can save 4 bytes by using `V\`` to reverse the string instead of ``O`.``.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Blatant port of [Arnauld's JS solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195606/58974) so go upvote him.

```
ÔcÈ^68%X/3%8
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=1GPIXjY4JVgvMyU4&input=IihbezwoKVtde308Pj59XSki)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
lambda x,s="([<{}>])":"".join(s[7-s.find(c)]for c in x[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoQgEADQq4hfM1BB7Ecg1UXMj7aQJmqUNHARz@6@53/xcPypdlrqtd7ffRWpCZMEPeYyG5RKyu50xBD00IbOEu@wobHuEZsgFkkr1fYGq3@II1gg9m8ERKyQi87F4B8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 67 bytes

```
procedure f(s)
r:="reverse"
return map(r(s),d:="([{<>}])",r(d))
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxCoAwEAT7vCKkugNfIOpHxELMCSmMsolahLw9RrBw2pldt@y@lAP7IvaE6JUCK7S9gVyCIEZB4gmvt/kgVNnYKmlM3ZAnNg3IMivx9vexzc4TK1254aLQSoZSHtO7@OoH)

Comment: Cool idea for finding the mirroring.  Is Icon a language worth looking into?

Comment: @Jonah Thank you! Yes, I think so, but keep in mind it's an old language. Icon is one of the first languages to have generators. A cool concept is the "goal directed evaluation" - if some expression fails, Icon automatically backtracks and generates another value(s) if there's a generator involved.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

This approach has many 13-byte solutions, although I can golf [Arnauld's 13 byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195628/53748) to 12 bytes.

```
QṢiⱮịQṢṭ2/FƲṚ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/w4c5FmY82rnu4uxvEfLhzrZG@27FND3fO@v//v7pGdLWNhmZ0bHWtjZ1dbaymOgA)**

#### How?

```
QṢiⱮịQṢṭ2/FƲṚ - Link: list of characters, P
Q             - de-duplicate (P)
 Ṣ            - sort (call this X)
   Ɱ          - map across (p in) P with:
  i           -   first index of (p) in (X)
           Ʋ  - last four links as a monad - i.e. f(P):
     Q        -   de-duplicate (P)
      Ṣ       -   sort
        2/    -   2-wise reduce with:
       ṭ      -     tack
          F   -   flatten (i.e. pair-wise reversal of sorted unique values)
    ị         - (left) index into (right)
            Ṛ - reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 302 bytes

```
{(({}(<()>))<({}[(((()()()()()){}){}){}])>{[()](<()>)}{}<({}[()])>{()(<()>)}{}<({}[(((()()())){}{}){}()])>{[()()](<()>)}{}<({}[()()])>{()()(<()>)}{}<({}[(((()()()){}()){}){}()])>{[()()](<()>)}{}<({}[()()])>{()()(<()>)}{}<({}[(((()()()()()){})){}{}])>{[()()](<()>)}{}<({}[()()])>{()()(<()>)}{}<>)<>{}}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1pDo7pWw0ZD005T0wbIjNYAAk0Y1KyuhaBYTbvqaA3NWIjK2upaiFpNkDhQIaoozASQdrBuiLpokBiGCXAzcJoC0q9JuTkw/4AdRZo5dpo2dtW1QHo0vEgML91kAA)

This is (currently) very poorly golfed, but I thought there ought to be at least one Brain-Flak answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 56 bytes

```
func[s][foreach c reverse s[prin select"[][()({}{<><"c]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYo7CsMwDIb3nEJ4sq9QjA@R9UdDUWRaKEmR0y7CZ3fxlI7fw3Qbq27gpd5o1M8uaIx6mN7lQUKmX7Wm1PC2505NXypnACOm6N1zyUGYx4wnVQoxgcNyoXd45/Sv4Hle3nMpM40f)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
“[({})]”©iⱮUịUɼ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xojepazdhHDXMPrcx8tHFd6MPd3aEn9/z//x8oHl1dG6sJAA)

A monadic link that reverses the input and input brackets of all their types.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 32 bytes

```perl
$_=reverse y/(){}[]<>/)(}{][></r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rYotSy1qDhVoVJfQ7O6NjrWxk5fU6O2Ojbazka/6P9/jehqGw3N6NjqWhs7u9pYzX/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>85</s> <s>84</s> <s>64</s> 60 bytes

60 bytes thanks to Neil

```c
p;f(char*s){for(p=strlen(s);p--;)putchar(s[p]^68%s[p]/3%8);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoAgEADAe6@QINgNpEMQwtJLwiAkSyhb1E7i241OcxgjD2NqZbJgzi30EbN9AvAcU7h2DxGJpSTkN/0PcWG9Tqr7HcZOIZXqfBL35jxgboSw0EIuSy4aW6Sm1A8)

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##FclBCoAgEADAe6@QINgNpEMQwtJLwiAkSyhb1E7i241OcxgjD2NqZbJgzi30EbN9AvAcU7h2DxGJpSTkN/0PcWG9Tqr7HcZOIZXqfBL35jxgboSw0EIuSy4aW6Sm1A8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")