# Mirror and reverse text

Tags: code-golf, string

Inspired by [I reverse the source code, ...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=I+reverse+the+source+code)

Your task, if you wish to accept it, is to reverse text and mirror select characters. Yes, yes, I know. Very surprising.

### Input

A string, `stdin`, an array of characters, or any other source of text. All characters of the input are guaranteed to be in the printable ASCII range (32-126).

### Output

The reversed text with some characters mirrored. To do this:

- You replace any occurrences of the characters `(`, `)`, `/`, `\`, `<`, `>`, `[`, `]`, `{`, or `}` in the text with the corresponding "mirrored" character: `)`, `(`, `\`, `/`, `>`, `<`, `]`,  `[`, `}`, or `{`.
- and then reverse the text.

You may assume a maximum line length of 255.

### Rules

- Standard loopholes apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), which means that the shortest answer in each programming languages wins. Consequently, I will not be accepting an answer.

### Testcases

```
(s)t/r\i<n>g[i]e{s} -> {s}e[i]g<n>i/r\t(s)
stringies -> seignirts
()/\<>[]{} -> {}[]<>/\()
{s}e[i]g<n>i/r\t(s) -> (s)t/r\i<n>g[i]e{s}
seignirts -> stringies
{}[]<>/\() -> ()/\<>[]{}
qwertyuiop database -> esabatad poiuytrewq
```

As seen above, the output should go back to the input if run through the program again.

[Sandbox link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18732/89298)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195600/horizontally-mirror-a-brainflak-program)

Comment: Related: [“Convenient palindrome” checker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28190/20260)

Comment: Also related: [I'm symmetric, not palindromic!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/142248/20260)

Comment: am I missing something, or the examples don't show the first rule in action? ie. shouldn't (s)t/r convert to r\t)s( ?

Comment: @Gnudiff The point is that you replace `(){}/\[]` with `)(}{\/][` and then reverse it, so the text looks "mirrored". The title was planned to be "mirror text" but that was too short, so I had to add some filler.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>61</s></sup> <sup><s>60</s></sup> 59 bytes

```python
lambda s,t="(/<[{}]>\)":[(c+t)[~t.find(c)]for c in s][::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBboMwEEX3nGLkDbbqBKWpVAkBy56gO@OFA4a6Sg2xByURolenJonSVsrK9vzx@zO/P@NHZ7dzk5fzXn3tagWeY05okolxkkXJSCpo9YRMfOO6MbamFZNN56ACY8FLkaarjZxRe/SQA42oI9QzTFxpMlu0wkg9@olwR8Khw7MNZRNkDG2E8YgSj87Y1mhPOPHatNY49BcpsFhSZoWQ4xUxCZkVSUnZTX7E5I8nuFrd8fyP7Y31C@f/jC8/D0ft8DyYrodaodoprwND@3BDVUPfmeGMTh8PSzuLXD6@u0GnMMTl8Py62cYc3tTe3ysvVTxFS5DIT0uUlwTTCJYU43j92RlLG4qMRdCHOZE2ZMQJVgWEZWB0wuf5SYbh5h8)

<sup>-1 byte thanks to @xnor.</sup>

Changed the lookup string, so that the `c in t` test is eliminated.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda s,b='(/<[{}]>\)':map(dict(zip(b,b[::-1])).get,s,s)[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHLboMwEEX3fMXIErItOUFJK1VCwLJf0B2wMMGhrhIgnkFJivh26jyUtlI2ftw7Pnc07s/02bXreZsW807vq1oDqirlIkrycSqzQvJ4r3tR2w2Jb9uLSlV5HC9WpZTLxpBChfImzGSQEFIQgXBMoKTIFTZpsya3pRlxYsoxvxl/bbxsvU2@jEkVCIbkbNtYg0wxNLZprSO8Wp4loyLJ8nK8Iaa8TLKoEPJuP2Oq5x3coh549Sf2zvqFq3/B15eHo3F0HmzXQ61JVxqNZxj0J9I19J0dzuTM8XApl4FLxw83mBgGXgzrt9ULV/Cud/hQXjd8CradA1InsC1cJxgHcJki58uvzrZiK0jKAHrfJwkWIiwy8GseYskgBEHK/xhgmp6knH8A)

<sup>-1 byte thanks to @xnor.</sup>

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>65</s></sup> 64 bytes

```python
lambda s,b=b'(/<[{}]>\)':s.translate(dict(zip(b,b[::-1])))[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNboMwEIX3nGLkjW3JCUpTqRIClj1Bd8DCBENdpYZ4BiUp4uzU@VHaSl15PG/8vecZzvTeu@3SZuWy1591owFVndVcxGkxzVVeSp7gmrx2uNdkRGN3JL7sIGpVF0my2lRSyluxkEFCyEBEwjOBkmJf2tTlXWErM@HMlGfhMOHahbYNMoUxJlUkGJK3rrMGmWJobOesJ7xKgSXjMs2Laroh5qJK87gU8i7/x1T/J7hZPfDql@2d9QNXf4yvLw9H4@k82n6ARpOuNZrAMBgq0g0MvR3P5M3xcBmXkc@mNz@aBEZejk8vmy1X8Kr3@Og87/gctb0HUiewDq4bTCK4bJHz9UdvnWgFSRnBEHKSaNlEM6xyCJ@ByReYZacqhFu@AQ)

Just for fun using idiomatic Python. (More idiomatic would be using `str.maketrans`, but it's *way* too long.)

-1 byte for both because the `\` in `'\)'` doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: In TIO,all the cases pass without using the 'r' prefix, so 60 bytes?

Comment: @dingledooper I was already editing my answer exactly for that :)

Comment: I really like your test rig, especially those unicode characters.

Comment: @xnor It's from [Noodle9's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202914/78410).

Comment: I found a byte-save with `(c+t)[~t.find(c)]` [TIO](https://tio.run/##bZBBboMwEEX3nGLkDbbqBKWpVAkBy56gO@OFA4a6Sg2xByURolenJonSVsrK9vzx@zO/P@NHZ7dzk5fzXn3tagWeY05okolxkkXJSCpo9YRMfOO6MbamFZNN56ACY8FLkaarjZxRe/SQA42oI9QzTFxpMlu0wkg9@olwR8Khw7MNZRNkDG2E8YgSj87Y1mhPOPHatNY49BcpsFhSZoWQ4xUxCZkVSUnZTX7E5I8nuFrd8fyP7Y31C@f/jC8/D0ft8DyYrodaodoprwND@3BDVUPfmeGMTh8PSzuLXD6@u0GnMMTl8Py62cYc3tTe3ysvVTxFS5DIT0uUlwTTCJYU43j92RlLG4qMRdCHOZE2ZMQJVgWEZWB0wuf5SYbh5h8 "Python 3 – Try It Online"). FWIW, Python 2 can do the second one for 63 as `lambda s,b='(/<[{}]>\)':map(dict(zip(b,b[::-1])).get,s,s)[::-1]`

Comment: The 3.8 walrus might also be useful: [TIO](https://tio.run/##bZBBboMwEEX3nGLkDbbqBKWp1AoBy56gO@OFA4a6Sg2xByUR4uzUJFHaSlnZnj9@f@b3Z/zs7Patd3OTl/Nefe9qBT4VFNO8eiI0ycQ4yaJkhIkVrl1jbE0rJpvOQQXGgpciTVcbOaP26CEHGlFHqGeYuNJktmiFkXr0E@GOhEOHZxvKJsgY2gjjESUenbGt0Z5w4rVprXHoL1JgsaTMCiHHK2ISMiuSkrKb/IjJH09wtbrj@R/bG@sXzv8ZX34ejtrheTBdD7VCtVNeB4b24Yaqhr4zwxmdPh6Wdha5fPxwg05hiMvh@XWzjTm8q72/V16qeIqWIJGfligvCaYRLCnG8fqrM5Y2FBmLoA9zIm3IiBOsCgjLwOiEz/OTDMPNPw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online"). Maybe there's something better there.

Answer (score 6):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
:R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JrPj/3yro/3@NYs0S/aKYTJs8u/TozNjU6uKQIE8/d0/X4FoA)

Well, um, yeah, Stax has a two-byte built-in that exactly does the job.

Comment: A Stax answer that you don't even have to pack to make it shorter, haha. xD

Comment: Why are you so hesitant to say that? I'm pretty sure that Canvas [has](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202995/92069) a 1-byte built-in.

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 33 bytes

```bash
tr '(<[{/)>]}\' ')>]}\\(<[{/'|rev
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxDgMhDAR7XkEHVHwA8RGg4BSLuCGJ7SSKCG/n0FUrzc4cle9rCWljQxrexTKz0ebafCHzJ/isZdmJp4yhx5awwOCpWAh7Q2Blnc8hpjKm2gdsoW0RdyA7VAzYOpKwGjOVEH22Tr2@QPJ74@Opb1XqURlO)

A straightforward solution seems best here. Really the only golfing is making sure that the backslash appears last in one of the arguments to tr, because then that backslash doesn't have to be escaped, saving 1 byte.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>65</s>  59 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Bubbler*

I/O format: array of characters

```javascript
a=>a.map(c=>(S='()/\\<>[]{}')[S.indexOf(c)^1]||c).reverse()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY@xbsMgEED3fgXyYhgK6m77FzpkxK5E7bN1UQoOR5JGjr/dpW2iRgkpI3f39N7a7A21HsfwbF0HS18upqyM/DAjb8uKr8qcC1XXRaWbac6FXkm0HXy@9rwVby/N6dQK6WEPnoCLpXWW3Abkxg2851pKmXESQfm6xsJWg8YGJpqzRsi1Q8vzXAimFIt/EGdD3MG4HOLRU4JFwaMdEChjf@@WRYCDRR8oRbiKyR4Splk3RaVqnpS4cf2RvQs6V19HJ4Murv8GXaqTNmfXKPs46Lv6NzqF2B7Ah@MO3cg6E8y7IcjuEEBxEEzHRoe7Y/Bw2C5f)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 (or 3?) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ºsK
```

Doesn't work for single-character inputs that are not in the mirror character-set (i.e. `"a"`).
Thanks to *@Grimmy* for this version.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0K5i7///NYo1S/SLYjJt8uzSozNjU6uLawE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##DcsxDgIhEEDRfk5BtoLEhAsQtrHzCEDBxgmZhlUGNRvc1gN4HEuP4kWQ@r@/clwI@/O@zZP4vd5imrdj/3741A9dsqq6eDLZJkcBG@/AtVBOhAxSaW@sC22HEXCANCCNoY4RGCllKpWh7S4Yq71UcH1gqduN1os4xxqXyAgN4h8).

```
º2äθ
```

Also works for single-character inputs that aren't in the mirror character-set.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0C6jw0vO7fj/X6NYs0S/KCbTJs8uPTozNrW6uBYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##DcsxDsIgFIDh/Z2CdCqJCYlzQw8CDDS@kLe0ykMNoV09gGfwEMZRdw/hRZD5//6F/URY10seO/G73UU35vp@7T@P77Puas8yqWhpmHUw5LDwBpwizYGQoZfKDtq4skEL2EBokNqQ2giMFGaKiaFsxg1a2V7C6Yox5TMtR3HwyU@eEQr4Pw).

**Explanation:**

```python
º     # Mirror the (implicit) input-string
      #  i.e. "(s)t/r\i<n>g[i]e{s}" → "(s)t/r\i<n>g[i]e{s}{s}e[i]g<n>i/r\t(s)"
 sK   # And remove the input-string from it
      #  → "{s}e[i]g<n>i/r\t(s)"
      # (after which it is output implicitly)

º     # Mirror the (implicit) input-string
      #  i.e. "(s)t/r\i<n>g[i]e{s}" → "(s)t/r\i<n>g[i]e{s}{s}e[i]g<n>i/r\t(s)"
 2ä   # Split it into two equal-sized parts
      #  → ["(s)t/r\i<n>g[i]e{s}","{s}e[i]g<n>i/r\t(s)"]
   θ  # Pop and only leave the mirrored second part
      #  → "{s}e[i]g<n>i/r\t(s)"
      # (after which it is output implicitly)
```

Comment: 3-byter `ºsK` [passes all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/0O7jA4vObfjv85/jWLNEv2imEybPLv06MzY1OriWq7ikqLMvPTM1GIuDU39GBu76NjqWi6gRCpQQTpQYSZQQwlQI1dxamZ6XmZRSTFXdW10rI2dfoyGJldheWpRSWVpZn6BQkpiSWJSYnEqAA). It fails if the input is a single letter, though.

Comment: @Grimmy Thanks, added :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda s,t=r"()/\[]{}<>":[[c,t[t.find(c)^1]][c in t]for c in s][::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9Bi4MwEIXv@RUhpwhqKXsT9Y/EFFKN7iw2ppkpRYq/3U2E7V56yuS9b95j/Erfi/vax6bbZ3O7DoZjTk0QMjt1Sr@2uhWVUn1OisoR3CD77HLWWvUcHCc9LoEfI2pVVcVZ73DzSyCOK7JkzuDs4a9YIg3gKhYb4k7Db8ZLpBDlAD4/yBL9DCRF0YosYzxESojyZwEnR4lJ8gEcyZDzUahX9Bveb1pke3TpFDqoXTsp0PaFGy9aHh8bv1OUIdoUMZb63AQWE4AWJgeBkKWL6zbdfCxuStftqZMZ@5CRiA@N7J12RP/1sP@wY/FdxO5PG2h9wOL5YMhcDdpEWIwjmYH7BR4rBfu8/wI)

**Input**: A sequence of character.
**Output**: The reversed string, as list of characters.

**How**:
For each character `c`:

- `c in t` checks if `c` is a bracket.
- `t.find(c)` finds the index of `c` in the bracket string. `t.find(c)^1` finds the index of the mirrored bracket, which is 1 more or 1 less than the index of `c`.
- `[c,t[t.find(c)^1]][c in t]` evaluates to the same character if `c` is not a bracket, otherwise evaluates to the mirrored bracket.
- `[::-1]` reverses the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 22 bytes

```
T`(/<[{}]>\\)`Ro
O^$`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvBCkIhEEDR/XxFiwJdlD8gblsG0U4NXzTIQPjKmYoQv91c33MrCpVl7NQxjUtSxvrWowtBp/MKp@s2HcZQrMXUQLa47Cli4w4slUomZFDaBOt8bB1mwAnyhDQHmSMwUi5UhaF1H60zQWl4fbHK703rc3NfZLktjGP/efwB) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`(/<[{}]>\\)`Ro
```

Transliterate the string `(/<[{}]>\)` to its reverse.

```
O^$`.
```

Reverse the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
Ｐθ‖ＴＦθ¿№βι←ι←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxCgIxEATQ/r5iywQUeyM2th6I2KlFLm50IV7uNpsTEb89Rq0G3sy4m2UXbSilzUFoYOpFjdo0e/QBnRzY9slHvqtqNaGWQB7UJua67GZAWsPud1tu0csXDGBICG2c8I/alPJKbzzS@brq17Tgk6ikAZPtrNgLDJHyUxgfY1PmU/gA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｐθ
```

Print the input string without moving the cursor.

```
‖Ｔ
```

Reflect the canvas. This mirrors the characters `()/\<>[]{}bdpq`.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop over the original string.

```
¿№βι
```

Is the current character a `b`, `d`, `p`, `q` (or any other lowercase letter that wouldn't have been transformed)?

```
←ι
```

If so then replace it with the original lowercase letter and move left.

```
←
```

Otherwise leave the current character, which might be a transformed `()/\<>[]{}`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>112</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>84</s></sup> 83 bytes

Saved a whopping 27 bytes thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
char*t,*b="()/\\<>[]{}";f(char*s){*s&&putchar((t=index(b,*s))?b[t-b^1]:*s,f(s+1));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDfboMgFIfv@xSEZA04G9PbtXUPIi5Bi46LWeTQ1D/x2R0ek65ZSm8IhwPfd/iVu7os57n8ljZycVScKOOJEMc0y8eJHiqGHeBjBNutubqlZMyddHNWHSti3@KfReZ2xdc@/4ggrhi87zk/TPOP1A3j42Z5Qros92jgLrFC6GOT1pnO1QjekUSE@o3yB7VvaH/D@ZuURMnGWN24ilFB30BQskuJoDTu@GFTsWX964uG@hpd/eIC51u1VrAKQOm60dbBC2yP2D6EHfALj@ng5FOWH1N/yF5NPCB6CKHlgv6XwRoCOp7mFpZJlMmQzGA89zzWeO5phbEGsSaEbfEPD2msoz/kFUa3iG5DaLug25uyrr/qiyFn6WQhQa0KBb5w8kzMRV97Z9WtfaGyqLJPVNP8Cw)

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZDBjoMgEIbvfQpCsgm4Nm6vrbUPIm6CFi2HtQjTtNb47C6OSbfZlF4Iw8D3DX@1bqpqmqqTtBHEUbmnjCdCpFleDCPd1Qw7jg@RO5gLzBVjsHdgq5NlZexb/FDmsC6/N8U2cnHN3OeG8@3Xbpx@pG4ZH1bzK3LLCw93HBIrhE7brMl1oQbnLUlEqN8of9D4hvY3wN@kJEpWxuoWakYF/XCCknVGBKXxje9WNZvXv75oqa/R1c8uP6NuG63cInBKN6224N5ge8T2Iewdv/CcD04@5kWa@UP2buI7ou8htJzR/zJYQkDHy9zCMokyGZIZjOeRxxLPI60w1iDWhLAd/uEpjWX0p7zC6A7RXQhtZ3R3VRb6iz4bcpQgS@nUolDOFyCPxJz1pQerrt0blUWVfaEap18)

Comment: @Bubbler Amazing recusive refactoring - thanks! :-)

Comment: You can save 1 byte by replacing `strchr` with `index` instead.

Comment: @dingledooper Nice one - thanks! :-)

Comment: @ceilingcat Clever - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## batch, <s>442</s> 408 bytes

```
@Echo off&Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z)do Set %%A=%%A
for %%B in ("(=)",")=(","<=>",">=<","[=]","]=[","{=}","}={","/=\","\=/")do Set "%%~B"
Set "_=%~1"
Call :M
Echo(!$!
Endlocal
Exit /B
:M
For /L %%C in (0,1,256)do (
If "!_:~%%C,1!"=="" Exit /B
Set ".=!_:~%%C,1!"
For %%D in ("!.!")do IF "!%%~D!"=="" (Set "$= !$!")Else (Set "$=!%%~D!!$!")
)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>111</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>75</s></sup> 69 bytes

```python
lambda s,b=r'()/\<>[]{}':[[c,b[b.find(c)^1]][c in b]for c in s][::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNasMwEIX3PsWgjSRQEtIUCsb2sifoTlbBP7KrksqONCYJxmd3ZTekLWSl0czoe0@vv@JHZw9zk@bzsfgq6wK8KFNHGd/lSSbVONFYykqUstw2xtas4u97pWQFxkKpms7BWnol43izVzNqjx5SYBFzhHmOO5ebxGatNEqPfiLCkXDocG1D24QxhjXCRcSIR2dsa7QngnhtWmsc@nUUWHdHK2KSKsl2OeO38SOmeOzgR@qOF39kb6xfuPgnvL48nbXD62C6HuoCi7LwOjC0DxUWNfSdGa7o9Pm0rPPIpeObG3QMA82Hp5f9gQp4LY7@3nmu6BQtQaK4LFGuCcYRLClSuv3sjGUNQ84j6INPZA0ZcYJNBuEzMDrp0/Sigrn5Gw)

Comment: I really like your test rig, especially those Unicode characters.

Comment: @xnor Thanks, have them memorised they're so useful. :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 111 bytes

```java
s->{var a="(\\<[{}]>/)";for(int i=s.length,j;i-->0;System.out.print(j<0?s[i]:a.charAt(9-j)))j=a.indexOf(s[i]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZAxT8MwEIX3/opTJSQbEbcDCyQNQp0RQ8ckg0mdcCF1gu9SqEJ@u3GqCokOluV737335EYfddTsPzwe@s4xNOGtBsZWVYMtGTurbuNFP7y1WELZaiJ40WhhXABcpsSaw3XscA@HoIkdO7R1VoB2NckzCrDtLA0H45LyXbusSKGCjacoHY/agd4sRZ4n2TgV6Uou46pzAi0Dbki1xtb8ftfEGEXpOt6diM1BdQOrPsSwaJL1E2VYPGo1Wz@zeIgaKWWz0Qrt3ny/VmLWZTz5@Fxldj@nuvrxX0eAa/dKLG/u1wQ/sLybURlfwErpsjQ9izBU3G3nZOf0Scg/5NqrteKiTYv5TN4LkrxyOSY2rUNFM9Lk6fx7aMgLucqTNCvGyQfBBKAOIIYFDoueDNYWHZMfp6xI0lUupP/8Mo5PA3Y97DXrN03mFw)

### Credits

- -1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Comment: Woops.. [127 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZAxT8MwEIX3/opTJCQbNW4HFpo0CDEjho5JBtd10gupE@xLoQr57cYtHQAxWCff@97d0zXyKONm9@rx0HeWoAl/MRC2ohqMIuyMuE1m/bBtUYFqpXPwLNHAOAO4dh1JCuXY4Q4OQWMbsmjqvARpa8cvKMBTZ9xw0Db9VjOoYO1dnI1HaUGuI1YUaT5OZbbgUVJ1lqEhwLUTrTY17Rmfq3mTYBxny2RzcqQPohtI9GEYVSy6UdG8SZcPaiWF2kv7SOw@bjjnzVoKNDv98VIxFcZdReQ8mXxyiXbedklh69WvzAD/bbpbOviEaH5GeXIFKyGV0j2xn82/7tawqzbNzm/ynjlOC1tgarI6x1KPbvLuciHUzjO@KNIsL8fJB0EHoA4gBgMFo3caa4OWnB@nvEyzRcG4f3vXlk4Ddj3sJMmtdPoL) in that case. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>32</s> <s>28</s> 26 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Bubbler!

-2 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog

```
|.rplc(;"0|.)@'([{/<>\}])'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxDsIgGIT3PsWfDgKJ0s5tJSYmTk6uwFArRYxpK2CMoX32igw3XO777rHmFPWwrwDBFkqoYnYUjpfzaZ2pnZ4drvNypuSAMA9Fw8QiCVpJBpnq7iPguicbBgg74gsrTDMwzY1UwS2oBuS8NYM2yv0LJoVoGJchTZFQkdTRMNH08SEZyujBWJ@MsHDZsELgNL0@yvrv24wT3FrfXlun0PoD)

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYyxDoIwFEV3vuKFwbaJFmbALiZOTq7QAbHgMwawrTGm4K/X2uEON/ece/cpJz3sCyCwhRyKkB2Hw/l09JSWab5wRmjtsko0q2SE6fnRfRfuWQKJ6m4T0LJnGwGEGmYz3WA1iqFGqZxZSQnEWI3jgMr8C2VZU4laujgFQgVyCAYG04aHaCgcRtQ2Gm6tZSWyhsbp@Vbafl44zXBtbXtpjSL@Bw). You don't need to append anything to the replacement array.

Comment: @Bubbler Of course I don't! I feel stupid, like so many times before...
Thanks!

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYyxDsIgGIT3PsWfDgKJ0s5tJSYmTk6uwFArRYxpK2CMoX32igw3XO777rHmFPWwrwDBFkqoYnYUjpfzaZ2pnZ4drvNypuSAMA9Fw8QiCVpJBpnq7iPguicbBgg74gsrTDMwzY1UwS2oBuS8NYM2yv0LJoVoGJchTZFQkdTRMNH08SEZyujBWJ@MsHDZsELgNL0@yvrv24wT3FrfXlun0PoD) minor adjustment

Comment: @FrownyFrog Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 1 [byte](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

Exactly. A 1 byte built-in.

```
↔
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyMTk0,i=JTI4cyUyOXQvciU1Q2klM0NuJTNFZyU1QmklNURlJTdCc1RSSU5HSUVTJTdE,v=8)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>69</s> 58 bytes

`+` to [@Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202927/68224)

-11 bytes thanks to @mazzy

```
$t='(/<[{}]>\)'
$args|%{$a="$_$t"[-1-($t|% i*f $_)]+$a}
$a
```

Expects input via [splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLboMwELzzFSu01NCAaNpKvQDqfxgrchNDXEU8bEdJRPh2upQ2ueTinfGMZ6zt2pMydq8OhwmrfJjQ5SxMMz6Moigj5qE0tb0GA8rcxw06nyfrJER3DUA/V4CbSKxQjuSb6LA53@6lES/n14/3bQx3tn7zQhbayKWm1FlT1FwLNdiRxcBoKKI1XWuSHdlYFJPfOqObWis7u6zSdaONs4sWRmmZFVwMS8TIRVakZfj38lEk2R59YGm6hc9Nt9ol6549R9x7f9We9ucuR912sJNOfkmrZpuyBJ3cQdfq48UZdepZBFcIBg8AuxjwDDmtb2aG0BNgBZ/dP02@W90QJO5jB0kx@/0VWk4zUT1JwhunHw)

Comment: ? `[--$i]` instead `[-++$i]`

Comment: ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJdb4IwFIbv@RUnrg6YEue2ZDdCluxnADFVjtiFUWyPX0F@uzsMJ1litpu2p@/T9@1Xpfdo7BqL4ixWYX0WFLreZBbXTRolvusIaXJ7GtbChAMxFzSIg2ngCToNQT2sQMz9dCRM4whz5sZWuHxfS2PDeMld@nh4en1ZjqGvps@O53rWp4lJ1KyM8lilWNvGHYPLHXKZ87RimRhz/THzlowqc4W2pSyqvFSGbKd5/iSZRXFadxZNnM6iSeJdVt6yZOzWBrqkq3mbdI3tvHrv1qLP/VY3fI903CpdQSZJLqTFFkPLQ5IZVFptj2Rwv3F9OMGwdhyAO5A7rTKwnFNgUCARGthJo@SiQAuqBFojrLTm@W/@c1uQ@psDWRR6D6RhaxFkefzPfqkzbHcjugOPQeCBH5Iwg5BfuFUMWg7m8h7ECt468JcQfGi2u9SsDC5uEERXajDqf0jchwS4@UFSpzl/AQ "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 69 bytes

```
func[s][reverse s forall s[s/1: any[select"()([][{}{<></\/"s/1 s/1]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BasQwDETPzVcIn5xDMb0uwR/Rq6KDmyipIXW2lrdlMfn2VJBaoIOYeaPJPJ/vPCN1yw3O5ZEmFMLMP5yFQWDZc9g2EBT3doOQnii88VSM7S0S1qMOfnCjM6qDLhGdynCYPkFKjmkF7EDHWOmLy2Mckl8xElc5zKVcvsjyf9vejYNHqs2gVlZkVTRqRNGohnJcU8ylofVAGrwbbTN8/3Iuz0fc7zCHEj6CsOnoqnTXtwUQvvZtbmXNqzewtIs6ejn/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), <s>76</s> 68 bytes

```
procedure f(s)
r:=reverse
return map(r(s),t:="([{/<>\\}])",r(t))
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BDoIwEEX3nKJ2NU1I2BPgIm0XVUYyCwpOB40hnF2LUeIs///vJUOXKb5eM08X7BdGdYVkCq5bxjtywoJRFo5qDDNwrkqpWw12rZrOuc0bXTKIMQXG/k8yBopgCpVv1zzVg0kQrvCJTlZnk1TsHDWxGyx5XNOmy0@rkzDFgTD9AjCVc01n/Xps8hwzNmScdo9k4cEjDZFYDn7drG@67IBjc3sgy3OhaVZ9kHAOCbX/vvEG)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -pl, 37 bytes

```perl
$_=reverse;y|(){}[]<>/\\|)(}{][><\\/|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYw7DgIhEEB7TmFhAYWhshK5CBCDcUIm2bDIjJoNy9VFGuv3KVCX8xjH27XCGyrBZdulat0FY7X3u5K9BWeN93ofQ5JiXT2abJPDAI26IK6YEwIJqbQ31oXWxQQwhTRFnAHPUBBgyliZxH8vlXh@oPL2wrUcHpHjPRJ818K4ZhqnsvwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 52 bytes

```php
<?=strrev(strtr($argn,$a='(/<[{}]>\\)',strrev($a)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBCoMwEEX3OUfAjFhygMZk10sYkUBFA20cJqkb8epNI7hp6erD472PM@asTBsT0biKMokEdzSFhru2ElJ1295ra6FqToc7ALhmo5kyOCOT9epouL@eeORDxIdP4jcuBfujfV3WkhmdRYQkyXoV9NT5ftziXtB7weSXEPPl9gE)

Glad that this time PHP has an elegant way of doing it ^^